# add class to navbar li tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#nav ul li').eq(0).addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

```css
#nav a:after {
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    transition: 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.68, -0.55, 0.265, 1.55);
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    content: "";
    left: 50%;
    right: 50%;
    height: 3px;
    bottom: 13px;
    background-color: #24252f;
}
```

```html
   <div id="nav">
    <ul >
        <li ><a href="/index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="/products/index.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about/index.html">ABOUT</a></li>        
        <li class="reservation"><a href="/partnerships/index.html">PARTNERSHIPS</a></li>                 
    </ul>
</div>
```

*This is my code, here i have navbar and i have to active li when user go on perticular page. My problem is i seprated the header(navbar) so how can i add or remove active classes to li *

Comment: Can you explain *i seprated the header(navbar)*?

Comment: You have to detect current active tab at your server side (e.g. php) then pass `active_tab` variable to your separated nav html part and via conditions place a class

Comment: please provide more details. the use of snippet alone make your question unclear

Comment: @Armen Don't misunderstand me. what did you mean by detecting active tab at server side whereas active state is only for client side. and how you confirm that he uses PHP? let OP correct the mistakes. then only we can suggest it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:
It will add 'active' class to the clicked element.
You can provide any styling you want in the active class.
You can check the DOM for clarity

HTML:

```
    <div id="nav">
      <ul >
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PARTNERSHIPS</a></li>           
     </ul>
</div>
```

Script:

```
$('#nav').on('click','ul > li',function(){
$('li').removeClass('active');
$(this).closest('li').addClass('active');
})
```

CSS

```
.active {
// Add styles
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BWojKa?editors=1111)

Answer (score 0):

you better add a class called active to a li tag also write some css to **.active** class and make use of it to whichever li you need to have for the pages respectively.

Comment: @Rajesh I think thats why they come from temporary(fake) accounts

Comment: @SagarV Surprising not one has done it yet. I guess everyone is considering the fact that user does not have enough reps and are taking easy.

Comment: @Blah Blah, please update your answer so that it justifies the term **answer**.

Comment: @Rajesh hey do you understand the question clearly? I didn't

Comment: @SagarV Nope. Even I dont and hence I added comment for explanation

Comment: @Rajesh no response from OP. raised a flag "unclear"

Comment: @BlahBlah the question is "how to add" the class, therefore your answer "add this class" does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you will include your nav div in index.html for every menu and index.html is separate for every menu, you can do the following :

1) give ids to your each li like

```
    <li id="li1"><a href="/index.html">HOME</a></li>
    <li id="li2"><a href="/products/index.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
    <li id="li3"><a href="/about/index.html">ABOUT</a></li>
```

2) and on each index.html add the following script

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
   $('respective li id').addClass("active"); 

   //for other lis remove active class using
   //following code :  $('li id').removeClass("active");
</script>
```

Comment: here what is respective ? i write like this <script type="text/javascript">
   $('respective li li3').addClass("active"); 

   //for other lis remove active class using
   //following code :  $('li id').removeClass("active");
</script>

Comment: respective li id means,for script on index.html for products use $('#li2').addClass("active"); and so on for other index pages

Answer (score -1):

You could just try putting the `.active` when you're in that particular page, like if you're in the home page:

```
<li><a href="/index.html" class="active">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="/products/index.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
<li><a href="/about/index.html">ABOUT</a></li>
<li class="reservation"><a href="/partnerships/index.html">PARTNERSHIPS</a></li>
```

Then if you're in the products:

```
<li><a href="/index.html">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="/products/index.html"  class="active">PRODUCTS</a></li>
<li><a href="/about/index.html">ABOUT</a></li>
<li class="reservation"><a href="/partnerships/index.html">PARTNERSHIPS</a></li>
```

Comment: what did you mean? `tab` also used to define multiple sections in single website.

Comment: He didn't mention using `tabs`, so I answered based on what he provided.

Comment: @Downvoter Can you please comment the reason? So that I can improve the answer

Comment: Re: He didn't mention....
@carlJan, read this part. `how can i add or remove active classes to li `

Comment: thanks for replay. i just want a java script which adds class to li of about, when i go to about page, so i get underline under about

Comment: This answer of mine is an alternative, he may or may not use it.